# creating a commission formula for custom object

Tags: formula-field, picklist

I am new to Salesforce and hopefully I'm asking the right question.

I have created a custom picklist under my Accounts object to determine what tier my customer has agreed upon. Tier 1 would be a commission base, Tier 2 would be a flat rate charge, and Tier 3 would just be other and would be $0. I created a formula field to have this Tier display on my custom objects tab called "Homes". In the Homes object I have a guide price, which is what we believe the home to sell for. I would like to create a formula that will calculate if there will be a commission off the guide price or a flat rate and display under my Homes objects.

```
    Integer forecast 

    if (Customer_Agreement_Tier_c == Tier 1 - Partner) {
       forecast = Guide_Price_c * 0.03;
    } else if (Customer_Agreement_Tier_c == Tier 2 - Subscription) {
       forecast = 1000;
    } else {
      forecast = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Your question is asking about a formula (which I take to mean "a formula field") but the example you've presented and the tag on your question suggests you might be using code, Apex, instead. Can you clarify whether you're looking to use a formula field or code here?

Comment: I was looking to create code inside of a formula field. If I'm way off please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In a formula field, you can use the [`CASE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&language=en_US&type=5) function. The following formula represents the logic in your Apex code snippet:

```
CASE(Customer_Agreement_Tier__c,
    "Tier 1 - Partner", Guide_Price__c * 0.03, 
    "Tier 2 - Subscription", 1000,
0)
```

The `CASE` function takes a field value and then checks different values and returns something different for each one. The last argument is the default when the field value does not equal any of the options.

Comment: More explanation would be better here, methinks. I'm an advocate of "explain more" in general, but it's even more important with people who are new to Salesforce. Specifically, mentioning how picklist fields normally need you to use `ISPICKVAL()` in formulas but how `CASE()` is one of the few functions that can work directly on picklists. That would probably set OP up for success later (and prevent a common misconception about how to use picklists).

Answer (score 0):

Formulas (used in formula fields, validation rules, flows, and a few other places) are similar to code, but they are different. They're pretty much functions stored (and evaluated) in the underlying database. [This trailhead module on Formulas & Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) is a good place to start if you're completely unfamiliar with them.

If you do have some familiarity, then [the official help page on Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is an indispensable reference.

With that out of the way, we can get to transforming your Apex-like example into a formula. The big thing here is that we only have the `IF(<condition>, <then>, <else>)` function available to us. There is no `ELSE()` nor `ELSEIF()`. So instead of those, we need to chain `IF()`s together to get a similar structure

```sql
IF(
    /* condition */
    Customer_Agreement_Tier_c == Tier 1 - Partner,

    /* then */
    Guide_Price_c * 0.03,

    /* else */
    IF(
        Customer_Agreement_Tier_c == Tier 2 - Subscription,
        1000,

        /* the final "else" part takes the role of an "else" in code */
        0
    )
)
```

That's the general structure, but the above formula will not be able to save for 2 reasons:

1. `Customer_Agreement_Tier__c` is a picklist, and they generally need to be handled using the `ISPICKVAL()` function
2. `Tier 1 - Partner` and `Tier 2 - Subscription` are string literals, and must be enclosed in quotes (single or double quotes will work, "smart" quotes will not) if you want to use them (as a final return value, as a parameter to a function, or in a comparison)

So the formula that would work here is

```sql
IF(
    /* Apex uses single quotes for string literals, so I'm using single quotes here */
    /*   for continuity/consistency */
    /* Also, custom field names in Salesforce always end with __c (two underscores) */
    ISPICKVAL(Customer_Agreement_Tier__c, 'Tier 1 - Partner'),
    Guide_Price__c * 0.03,
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Customer_Agreement_Tier__c, 'Tier 2 - Subscription'),
        1000,
        0
    )
)
```

If you have many picklist values to compare against, the nested chain of `IF()`s can get quite deep. When you're *only comparing against a single field*, the `CASE()` function makes more sense (much less nesting, generally less typing).

`CASE()` takes a single value as its first parameter
a default value as its final parameter
and then any number of target - value pairs in between
It's also one of the few functions that can work directly on picklists, so you don't need to use `ISPICKVAL()` or `TEXT()`

```sql
CASE(
    Customer_Agreement_Tier_c,
    'Tier 1 - Partner', Guide_Price__c * 0.03,
    'Tier 2 - Subscription', 1000,
    0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on this. am I able to add an if statement under the Tier 1

        CASE(
                Customer_Agreement_Tier_c,
                'Tier 1 - Partner', if (Revised_Guide_Price__c != null) 
                              Revised_Guide_Price__c * 0.03
                              else Guide_Price__c * 0.03 ,
                'Tier 2 - Subscription', 1000,
    0
)

Comment: @nrw2631 I'm actually not sure. A brief test shows me that `IF()` for the "value" part of a target-value pair is allowed (as long as both the "then" and "else" values are of the same type, and also the same type as the rest of the "values" in the `CASE()`). At that point though, I'd probably advise that you go with the nested `IF()` approach. Also, the `IF()` function always needs all 3 of its parameters passed into it, so it would be something like `IF(Revised_Guide_Price__c = null, Revised_Guide_Price__c * 0.03, Guide_Price__c * 0.03)`. The "then" and "else" parts belong inside the parens.